# No Crystal é possível ligar-se a um WebSocket

Tags: websocket, crystal-lang

Estou a iniciar no *Crystal* e quero tentar criar uma ligação de um WebSocket server com o Crystal como client, é possível de o fazer, existe alguma livraria para isso ou a linguagem crystal já traz?

Comment: Não seria a classe `Socket`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encontrei isto no [KeepCoding](http://php.wekeepcoding.com/article/14009061/How+to+open+a+connection+to+a+WebSocket+server+in+Crystal+(use+Crystal+as+client)) que me ajudou a resolver a minha dúvida, pode-se ainda consultar o link do [GitHub](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/pull/1369/files) para mais informações:

```
socket = HTTP::WebSocket.open("example.com", "/connect")
socket.send "action"
message = socket.receive
```